# Laravel cant flatten array after collection->forget

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, relational-database

I have a loop inside loop on Laravel collection, and sometimes i need to delete some objects from second loop collection. Here is the code

```
public function remove_if_found($id)
{
    $all_groups = Group::all();
    $all_groups->load('templates');

    foreach ($all_groups as $group)
    {
        foreach ($group->templates as $key => $template)
        {
            if($template->id = $id)
            {
                $group->templates->forget($key);
            }
        }
    }

    return $all_groups;
}
```

The problem is that collection of group->templates turns from simple(not assoc) array to object. Here is example how response looks

[image: explanation]

I am trying to flatten $group->templates->flatten() but in final response templates are still as object but not as array.

This test flatten works

```
    ...
    foreach ($all_groups as $group)
    {
        foreach ($group->templates as $key => $template)
        {
            if($template->id = $id)
            {
                $group->templates->forget($key);
            }
        }

        return $group->templates->flatten()//This code works i get fluttened array
    }
```

But final variant still returns me object instead of array

```
    $all_groups = Group::all();
    $all_groups->load('templates');

    foreach ($all_groups as $group)
    {
        foreach ($group->templates as $key => $template)
        {
            if($template->id = $id)
            {
                $group->templates->forget($key);
            }
        }

        $group->templates->flatten()//Use flatten here
    }

    return $all_groups;//Templates are returned not as an array but still as an object (Same variant as on attached image)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `values()` to reset the keys and `setRelation()` to replace the relationship:

```php
public function remove_if_found($id)
{
    $all_groups = Group::all();
    $all_groups->load('templates');

    foreach ($all_groups as $group)
    {
        foreach ($group->templates as $key => $template)
        {
            if($template->id = $id)
            {
                $group->setRelation('templates', $group->templates->forget($key)->values());
            }
        }
    }

    return $all_groups;
}
```

You can also use `except()` instead of `forget()`:

```php
public function remove_if_found($id)
{
    $all_groups = Group::all();
    $all_groups->load('templates');

    foreach ($all_groups as $group)
    {
        $group->setRelation('templates', $group->templates->except($id));
    }

    return $all_groups;
}
```

Comment: Yes it works, everything is ok now, I do not understand what setRelation does, will google it now, thanks)

Comment: It sets the relationship's value in the `Model::$relations` property.

Comment: It is something like "temporary" relation?

Comment: No, it replaces the existing value. For attributes, you would use something like `$group->name = strtolower($group->name);`. For relationships, this requires `setRelation()`.

Comment: You are awesome, Thanks Jonas)